# overflow scroll greyed and div not taking all the height

Tags: html, css

Its taking me hours without success.
Im trying to create a layout: [Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-dawn-pl12i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.MyNavbar {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Main {
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.Main:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.Sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Content {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  float: left;
}

.ContentHeader {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.ContentData {
  background-color: lightblue;
  /*margin-top: 10px;  */
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  <div style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="MyNavbar">myNavbar</div>
    <div class="Main">
      <div class="Sidebar">
        Sidebar
      </div>

      <div class="Content">
        <div class="ContentHeader">
          ContentHeader
        </div>

        <div class="ContentData">
          ContentData<br /><br />

          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <br />

          <h3>End of ContentData</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The ContentData section should take all the space until the bottom of the display. If there is too much content, the scrollbar of that section should allow viewing the rest of the content.

But Im not able to:
- make the scroll bar work. It keeps greyed out.
- If there is no content (by removing the "Lorem Ipsums") content data does not take all the height i want to fill the display size.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove comment from following code.

```
.Content {
  /*height: 90%;*/
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  float: left;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.MyNavbar {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.Main {
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.Main:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.Sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Content {
  height:100%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  float: left;
}

.ContentHeader {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.ContentData {
  background-color: lightblue;
  /*margin-top: 10px;  */
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  <div style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="MyNavbar">myNavbar</div>
    <div class="Main">
      <div class="Sidebar">
        Sidebar
      </div>

      <div class="Content">
        <div class="ContentHeader">
          ContentHeader
        </div>

        <div class="ContentData">
          ContentData<br /><br />


          <h3>End of ContentData</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```